# image slider when empty image

Tags: php, html, slider

i use this template for my image slider "https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider"

i try to change a image if image1 is empty(NULL) to image2, there is my sample code i have try but doesnt work.

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:550px;overflow:hidden;">
 <?php
if (!empty ($upload_dir.$data['image1'])){
    ?>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$data['image1']; ?>" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$data['image1']; ?>" />
        </div>
<?php
}else{
    ?>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$data['image2']; ?>" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$data['image2']; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php
}
?>
```

this code is work when image1 is able on databases, but when it null the image is not change as image2

Comment: It's because your `$upload_dir` is not empty so `$upload_dir.$data['image1']` would not be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `$upload_dir` is not empty so `$upload_dir.$data['image1']` would not be empty.

Try changing the condition to:

```
if (!empty($data['image1'])) {
   ...
}
```